# Need guidance with creating Django based dashboard

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, data-manipulation

I'm a beginner at Django, and as a practice project I would like to create a webpage with a dashboard to track investments in a particular p2p platform. They do not have a nice dashboard (but provide excel file with all data). As I see it, main steps that I need to do in this project are as follow:

1. Create login so that users would have account where they upload their excel files.
2. Make it possible to import excel file to a database
3. Manipulate/calculate data for it to be later used in dashboard
4. Create dashboard.
5. Host webpage.

After some struggle I have implemented  point no. 2, and will deal with 1 and 5 later. But number 3 is my biggest issue now.

3. I'm completely unsure what I need to do, and google did not help. I need to calculate data before I can make dashboard from it. Union two of the tables, and then join them together with a third table, creating some additional needed calculated fields. Do I create a view in the database and somehow fetch this data to Django? Or do I need to create some rules so that new table would be created at the time of the import? I think having table instead of a view would have better performance. Or maybe I'm doing it completely wrong, and should take completely different approach for this kind of task? Also, is SQLite a good database for a task (I'm using it, because it was a default in Django)?
4. I assume for vizualization part I will need to do it with some JavaScript library, such as D3? Which then would use data from step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 3 there is 2 way, either do these stuff and save the result in your database or you can do it when you need it using django model features like annotation, aggregation and etc.

- Option 1 requires to add a table for you calculation which is Models in django.
- Option 2 requires to create a doing the annotations in a view or model managers and then using them in views.

[Django docs: Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/)

Which is the best is depended on how big your data is, how complicated the calculation is and how often you need them.

And for database; SQLite is just a database for development use not the production and surly not with a lot of data and a lot of calculations. The recommended database for django is postgresql which is pretty good at handling millions and even billions of data and doing heavy calculation.

And for vizualization you should handle it on the template side which is basically HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I have an idea now. Shoud I use pandas for calculations, or do you suggest something else?

Comment: It depends on your calculations, pandas is a better option than doing the calculations with pure python but still not as fast as database if you can write good queries.